# Add multiple in clauses depending if variable is blank or not (stored procedure) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How am I able to get this to work I want it to add in clause if the value is not blank and not write the in clause if the value is blank. I have already tried with using OR and It runs but does not give me the results I want. I am using SQL Server 2008.

My variables are:

```
@orderNumber varchar(max), 
@itemCode varchar(max), 
@shipTo varchar(max), 
@orderQty varchar(max), 
@orderType varchar(max)
```

Now I took out a bunch of the stored procedure as it is a total of 600 lines but this should explain exactly what I want to do. I have searched high and low and have not found any solutions for this.

The query is:

```
SELECT 
    u.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, u.ORDER_TYPE,
    u.ORDER_QTY, u.ORDER_NUMBER,
    u.SHIP_TO_NAME, u.ITEM_CODE AS SET_BOX,
    ii.ITEM_CODE,
    U.LANGUAGE_DESC
FROM 
    UnReleased_DeliveriesSet u
JOIN 
    SetDetails s ON u.item_code = s.SetCode
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    InventorySetBox i ON u.ITEM_CODE = i.ITEM_CODE
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    InventorySetBox ii ON ii.ITEM_CODE = s.ItemCode
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    SET_BOX_TYPE SB ON SB.ITEM_CODE = u.ITEM_CODE
WHERE 
    u.item_code LIKE '%.set%'
    AND u.item_code NOT LIKE '%NN-%SET%'
    AND ii.ITEM_CODE IS NOT NULL
    AND ii.SUBINVENTORY_CODE <> 'BMS'
    AND u.ITEM_CODE NOT IN ('inner query')
```

This is what I want to do:

```
    AND 
      CASE WHEN @itemCode != '' 
              THEN u.ITEM_CODE IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@itemCode,',')) 
           WHEN @orderType != '' 
              THEN u.ORDER_TYPE IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderType,',')) 
           WHEN @orderQty != '' 
              THEN u.ORDER_QTY IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderQty, ','))  
           WHEN @orderNumber != '' 
              THEN u.ORDER_NUMBER IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderNumber, ',')) 
           WHEN @shipTo != '' 
              THEN u.SHIP_TO_NAME in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@shipTo,   ','))  
      END
GROUP BY 
    u.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, u.ITEM_CODE,
    U.LANGUAGE_DESC,
    i.item_box_quantity,
    sb.BOX_TYPE, sb.set_box_qty,
    ii.ITEM_CODE,
    S.SetCode, RELEASED_STATUS,
    u.ORDER_TYPE, u.ORDER_QTY, u.ORDER_NUMBER, u.SHIP_TO_NAME
```

Comment: Have you considered using table valued parameters instead of delimited lists? It is easier to work with and they will be way faster than any splitter can even think about.

Comment: My split function is a table valued function. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes. table valued parameters are incredibly fast and super simple to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
and 1 = case
         when @itemCode != '' then case
                                    when u.ITEM_CODE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@itemCode,',')) then 1
                                    else 0
                                   end
         when @orderType != '' then case
                                     when u.ORDER_TYPE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderType,',')) then 1
                                     else 0
                                    end
         when @orderQty != '' then case
                                    when u.ORDER_QTY in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderQty,',')) then 1
                                    else 0
                                   end
         when @orderNumber != '' then case
                                       when u.ORDER_NUMBER in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderNumber,',')) then 1
                                       else 0
                                      end
         when @shipTo != '' then case
                                  when u.SHIP_TO_NAME in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@shipTo,',')) then 1
                                  else 0
                                 end
         else 0
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

A really hacky way using `case` expressions:

```
and 1 = case when @itemCode = '' or u.ITEM_CODE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@itemCode,',') s) then 1 else 0 end
and 1 = case when @orderType = '' or u.ORDER_TYPE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderType,',') s) then 1 else 0 end
and 1 = case when @orderQty = '' or u.ORDER_QTY in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderQty,',') s)  then 1 else 0 end
and 1 = case when @orderNumber = '' or u.ORDER_NUMBER in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderNumber,',') s) then 1 else 0 end
and 1 = case when @shipTo = '' or u.SHIP_TO_NAME in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@shipTo,',') s) then 1 else 0 end
```

A still rather hacky way using `or`

```
and (@itemCode = '' or u.ITEM_CODE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@itemCode,',') s))
and (@orderType = '' or u.ORDER_TYPE in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderType,',') s))
and (@orderQty = '' or u.ORDER_QTY in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderQty,',') s))
and (@orderNumber = '' or u.ORDER_NUMBER in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@orderNumber,',') s))
and (@shipTo = '' or u.SHIP_TO_NAME in (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@shipTo,',') s))
```

A much better way would use dynamic sql to conditionally build your `where` statement and pass your parameters to [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Reference:

- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)